# Do I need to leave the Schengen area between two 180-day periods?

Tags: visas, schengen

I just can't find the answer I am looking for so I hope you can help me!

I am a bit confused because of the new rules from October 2013.

So we are Australian, and were in Schengen between 23/07/14 and 26/09/14 (66 days) and came back in 27/12/14 and the end of the 180 day period is 18/01/15 (23 days) ... so my question is... do we need to leave schengen for the new 180 day period to begin? And then we would get 90 days within the 180 day period?

We are in France, so thinking we could go to the UK or Andorra for a day (I just found out that Andorra is not Schengen, is this true?!)

Or is it that you can spend a maximum of 90 days in any 180 day period, so we couldn't spend 90 days from 20th january because we spent 23 days already (so could only spend 67 days until we need to leave).

Comment: Andorra is not Schengen area, customs checks when returning from Andorra can range from a "keep driving" to a full vehicle/belongings check.

Answer (score 2):

It is a rolling period. Within *any* 180 days, you may only be in the Schengen area for 90 days.

So your question is not actually applicable. You will not need to leave Schengen unless there is some 180 day period such that within that period, you were in the Schengen are for 91 days.

In your example, if you were in the Schengen area from 23/07/14 to 26/09/14 and then return on the 1st of January 2015, you can stay for 90 days starting with the 1st of January.

On the other hand, 23/07/14 to 26/09/14 in Schengen and then 27/12/14 to the 10th of April 2015 would not be allowed, as in the 180 day window starting from the 27th of December, you would be in the area for more than 90 day.

Comment: Oh thank you! Yes, you have answered my question. So I can stay now until the 26th March, then have to go back out again until 23rd June. Thank you so so much, I so appreciate your help